# Variável e escopo além do arquivo .cpp C++

Tags: c++, scope

Existe a possibilidade de um arquivo .cpp "enxergar" uma variável declarada no em outro arquivo .cpp? 
   Exemplo: no arquivo main.cpp há uma variável global int myVar. É possível acessá-la em outro arquivo, no my.cpp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variáveis declaradas em escopo global do arquivo pode ser acessadas por outros arquivos utilizando o extern.

foo.cpp

```
int myVar = 10;
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

extern int myVar;

int main() {
  std::cout << myVar << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Para compartilhar variáveis é recomendável declarar elas em arquivos de cabeçalho .h, e elas também devem ser constantes ou pre-processadas para não interferir no comportamento das outras funções que dependem delas.

Comment: Opa, valeu Vinícius. Muito Obrigado. Funcionou aqui.

Comment: @mrsoliver se minha resposta foi útil para você marque-a como resposta correta.